# Cómo es que la expresión regular "[\\?&]paramName=([^&#]*)" obtiene un parámetro

Tags: javascript, regex

Resulta que encontré esta función:

```
function paramValue( paramName ){
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+paramName+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp ( regexS );
    var tmpURL = window.location.href;
    var results = regex.exec( tmpURL );

    if( results == null )
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
}
```

la cual me entrega un valor, para después utilizarla en una petición AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    //MODIFICACION 2 lineas (para usar jsonp sobre un archivo en servidor de prueba[crossdomain])
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "https://widgets.inacap.cl/portal_alumno/ws/in.php?sesi_ccod=" + paramValue('sesi_ccod'),
    //url: "http://" + paramValue('dominio') + "/portal_alumno/ws/in.php?sesi_ccod=" + paramValue('sesi_ccod'),
    //url: "http://172.16.110.43/tportalvp/aplicaciones/widget_ia/ws/in.php?sesi_ccod=" + paramValue('sesi_ccod'),
    success: function(data){};
```

Por lo que veo, desde la consola de Chrome​ la petición es GET, quedando la URL de la siguiente manera:

`https://widgets.inacap.cl/portal_alumno/ws/in.php?sesi_ccod=&callback=jQuery2240484312704416485_1491105594768&_=1491105594769`

y los parámetros que envía son los siguientes:

> sesi_ccod:
>   callback: jQuery2240484312704416485_1491105594768
>   - :1491105594769

Bueno y todo esto me entregará un JSON con toda una información:

```
paramValue es: &callback=jQuery22408743659077827339_1491100541998&_=1491100541999
```

Pero no logro entender cómo obtengo ese valor. ¿Quién me puede explicar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Las expresiones regulares (regex) son un lenguaje que permite validar un texto, ver si coincide con un patrón avanzado, dividir un String en un array, o reemplazar. Se podría decir que tienen *comodines* como los típicos `*` y `?`, pero muchísimo más avanzados.

Es un tema muy amplio, pero encontrarás mucha información en la web al respecto. Los enlaces más importantes están listados en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info.

**¿Qué hace el regex `[\?&]paramName=([^&#]*)`?**

El regex de tu código es aplicado a la URL actual. Lo que hace es obtener el valor del parámetro que estás pasando a la función (`'sesi_ccod'`), y pasarlo como parámetro a la URL del AJAX.

En particular, el regex se convierte en:

```
/[\?&]sesi_ccod=([^&#]*)/
```

Significado:

- `[?&]` - Coincide con un caracter: un `?` o un `&` (el separador de los parámetros de búsqueda de la URL).
- `sesi_ccod=` - Coincide literalmente con ese texto.
- `([^&#]*)` - Los paréntesis son un grupo, por lo que **capturan** todo lo que coincida con el su patrón:

  - `[^&#]*` - Caracteres que no sean `&` ni `#`, repetidos entre 0 e infinitas veces (todas las veces que se pueda). Por eso capturan todos los caracteres permitidos del valor del parámetro.

Y el texto capturado por el grupo, si coincidió, es devuelto por `results[1]`.

Por ejemplo si `window.location.href` (la URL actual) es

```
http://url.com?q=bla&sesi_ccod=abcde&z=fin
                               ^^^^^
```

obtendrías el texto subrayando en `results[1]`. Sin embargo, por el resultado que estás mostrando, ese parámetro no existe (no fue pasado) en tu página actual.

De esa forma es que se genera la nueva URL, utilizando el mismo valor del parámetro `sesi_ccod` que el de la página actual.

> Nota: no hay problema con los valores que estás utilizando, pero esa función devolvería valores incorrectos en muchos casos con caracteres especiales. No te recomiendo usarla en otros casos a menos de que estés convencido de cómo funciona.

---

Por otro lado, si te estás preguntando cómo es que se genera el parámetro `callback`, no está relacionado en absoluto con el regex ni con tu función, sino que es como se utiliza [JSONP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (no confundir con JSON). Además, podrás encontrar más información de cómo lo implementa jQuery en https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/.

Comment: Si alguien tiene a mano algún enlace que esté mejor para explicar JSONP, sería genial que editen.